# Asterisk and Java : Park action don't return parking slot

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, asterisk-java

I have a Java application that interacts with an Elastix server. 
I'm using asterisk-java library. I can park someone and get the Asterisk Manager Interface's response but it is incomplete. This response give me those info :

```
org.asteriskjava.manager.response.ManagerResponse: actionId='null'; message='Park successful'; response='Success'; uniqueId='null'; systemHashcode=698702159
```

I would like to know on which parking slot the person was put.

I know that the secretary that pressed the button to transfer the customer should hear a voice saying *"XXX has been park at [a parking slot number]"* but I would like to get this number with Java.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Park application NEVER return parking slot.

it PLAY parking slot.

You have rewrite parking app or read events.

Comment: Ok, I'll check the events I think then. Thank you!